# Which database to use for flex standalone application?

Tags: database, apache-flex, air, flex3

I am planning to develop a standalone application, which infact will be used for personal purposes. So only single user access may be there. I want to develop it in Flex. Just want some opinions from the gurus over here :

1. Whether i should use Flex or AIR (I know only Flex, AIR i need to start learning)
2. Which database i should use? SQLLite or HSQLDB or some other.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Happy Coding

Regards,
PK

Comment: I don't think any of the answers (as of this time) adequately express that If you already know flex then you already know Air. It's the same thing for the most part. Air has a few more functions but you should have no anxiety about Air if you're already using Flex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a standalone application you will need to use Air, FLEX is a framework so you can use it into your Air application.

Air come with SQLLite ready to use, if you dont want to use SQLLite you will have to find a way to communicate with your database : a gateway server (php, java, ...) or found a ready to use socket driver, or write it yourself.

Edit:
[Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/07/adobe-air-developers-toolbox-resources-and-tutorials/) a starter page where you can found for example Air sample and tutorial

In [this](http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2008/04/07/introduction-to-sqlite-in-adobe-air/) one, an example of using an SQLite database. You can download the code of the sample application

Comment: i just installed air. but i am not able to find the SQLLite installation anywhere in ma m/c. Can you please help me. infact am not even sure where does the AIR got installed into. But it's working :)

Comment: SQLite in integrated to the Air SDK you will not find the SQLite installation. I have updated the post with some links to example / sample

Comment: okay, lemme ask one more doubt : do air also have platform and sdk different. Like flash player and flex sdk, do we have both different for air? because am not seeing any installation of air folder :(

Answer (score 1):

1. BOTH!  Start in Flex because you know it and migrate to AIR so you have a local desktop app for your own use.  You can then offer that to your eventual users.
2. Doesn't really matter at the moment, you might even consider not using a db at all and just persisting to the file system for ease of configuration etc. while it is just you.  However when you get going you will need to take your database seriously at which point I would go for MySQL to start with rather than either of the ones you mention.  The reason I say that is that it gives you more than a temporary solution as MySQL will support you as you grow and the sooner you embed it the better.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB is the simplest and, if your application will not product lot of data, the easiest to distribute with standalone application. This is good database to store data in desktop app`s.